# How can I disable or demote ReSharper's "Add 'xyz' to the abbreviations list?"

Tags: resharper

I'm using ReSharper 6.1. Great tool, but one thing annoys me and I can't figure out how to change it: I think the order of options presented when an abbreviation breaks style rules is backward. Our codebase is littered with variable and method names containing "XML," "ID," etc. ReSharper catches these (which I like) but instead of offering to change the name as its first option, it uses the 'add xyz to abbreviations list' as the first option.

This ordering drives me nuts because I frequently add an abbreviation that I don't want by accident. Then I have to spend some time clicking through the config menus to remove the abbreviation. When I do catch myself before adding it, I have to hit the down arrow to reach the option I want; I'm a Vim/VsVim user, so as a rule I try to avoid use of the arrow keys.

So - does anyone know how I can switch the order of the suggestions, or even disable the 'add xyz...' option entirely? Thanks!

Comment: This is clearly not too localized if there is an open issue about it on JetBrains...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do this.

There was a [thread on JetBrains](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/305794) asking about this exact issue, but no resolution. They did open a [usability ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-273952), so you can always throw your support behind it.

Comment: Thanks, I voted. Wish it was a higher priority!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/08/resharper-701-bugfix-update-available/) post, this issue should be resolved in version 7.01